# ServerObject aspImage in Win 2008 64-bit

Tags: windows, asp-classic, 64-bit

Does anybody have any experience/ knowledge in installing the aspImage.dll on a 64-bit Windows 2008 platform?

I have a Classic ASP site that uses this component and would badly need to get the dll running. I have tried checking support documents for these to no avail.

Would really do appreciate your response.

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.serverobjects.com/comp/Aspimage.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if you want to use a 32-bit COM object on a 64-bit machine you'll want to register the COM object use the regsvr32 executable located in the Windows\SysWOW64 folder.  In IIS you'll want to go to the application pool advanced settings and select true for the Enable 32-bit Applications setting.

Comment: Thanks for this Nathan.

Follow-up question, do I still need to register the dll in the Component Service as well?

Thanks again!

Comment: I apologize, but I'm not familiar with the specific COM object you are using.  Is it normally hosted as a COM+ service?  If it is a plain old COM object I would not think you should have to register it in component services.

Comment: Thanks! Just a note for anyone else - make sure you drop the .DLL in syswow64 and then run the regsvr32.exe in syswow64 on that .DLL.

Comment: For me you also needed to do the Com+ modifications as described in the post by "Dennis"

Answer (score 7):

Exactly the same problem migrating from server 2003 iis6 to server 2008 iis7 64 bit. Creating a new com+ application solved the problem.

I created the application I named aspimage using the com+ wizard as a server app, used local service for permissions, left default creator owner role alone, added users everyone and authenticated. After the folders were created, I added a component using the wizard. Already registered component, (assumes regsvr32 %systemroot%\syswow64\aspimage.dll ) and selected the check boxes 32 bit registry and details to ensure selection of the correct dll. Finish and the process worked. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This worked for me. Well explained.  I had tried the suggestions in the other posts about copying the file SysWow64, doing the regsvr32 there and doing the registration as an admin. These were all critical steps but not sufficient to get it working. This Com+ application setting up is what got it working. Well done.

Comment: Had the same issue with AspQmail /ASPMail ServerObjects. Had to uncheck the "Enforce Access checks..." for it work though.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had similar problems this week:

To answer the question about registering, yes, you still have to run their registration tool and enter your license key.  If using UAC, remember that both the regsvr32 and the aspimage's registration app must be run "as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to have the ServerObject aspImage.dll component run in a Windows 2008 64-bit platform server by creating a COM+ Application and using the aspImage.dll as a COM+ component.

I've also learned that any 32-bit components used in IIS that will be run in a 64-bt server needs to go through this process too.

For more details on delving on COM+ components and apps, please refer to this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725986.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you need to do anything special with the registration program?
I successfully ran the registration program, but when I execute my code, it tells me that the evaluation period has expired.

Comment: Not sure about the registration program... what registration program are you talking about?